# VSCode Mocha typescript tests debug steps through the transpiled file instead of the source .ts file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

When I start debugging mocha tests using the config below, VSCode steps through the transpiled code instead of the original Typescript code. Which setting should I change to step through the original code?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "args": [
                "--require",
                "ts-node/register",
                "--timeout",
                "999999",
                "--colors",
                "${workspaceFolder}/tests/**/*.ts"
            ],
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "name": "Mocha Tests",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
            "request": "launch",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "pwa-node"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `outFiles` fixed the problem:

```
"outFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js",
    "!**/node_modules/**"
],
```